# Storing value in $a0 is fine, storing it in $a1 gives "memory out of bounds"

Tags: assembly, memory, mips, qtspim

If I place a string into $a0 for printing (2nd line of main), everything is fine. If I place it into $a1 instead (change $a0 to $a1), QtSpim returns "memory address out of bounds."

I can see that QtSpim starts filling those registers before it even gets to my code (lines posted below). Does anyone know what these registers are used for? Should I just avoid using argument registers for my own code? I'm pretty new to MIPS and appreciate any help or advice.

Thank you!

QtSpim text lines showing registers being filled:

```
[00400000] 8fa40000  lw $4, 0($29)            ; 183: lw $a0 0($sp) # argc 
[00400004] 27a50004  addiu $5, $29, 4         ; 184: addiu $a1 $sp 4 # argv 
[00400008] 24a60004  addiu $6, $5, 4          ; 185: addiu $a2 $a1 4 # envp
```

My code:

```
.data
product:
.asciiz "The Booth's Algorithm Product is:  "
multiplicand:
.asciiz "Enter the Multiplier: "
multiplier:
.asciiz "Enter the Multiplicand: "
counter:
.asciiz "\nThe Number of Additions and Subtractions is: "
.text

main:
    li $v0, 4                   # syscall code for printing string
    la $a0, multiplicand        # loads the string into a0
    syscall
    li $v0, 5                   # syscall code for inputting integer
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0                # places the integer into s0
```

Comment: For printing service you must provide memory address of string. Memory address is also 32 bit integer at your MIPS platform, i.e. you can provide whatever number in `a0` to printing service, and it will try to use it as memory address to load single letters from memory one by one and print them. If the address points to invalid memory, it will crash. The printing service has no idea you did put string address into `a1` instead and doesn't care, its code is written to use `a0` and so it will, ignoring your value in `a1`.

Comment: The second question is about how C/C++ languages start `main` of app with command line argument list, passing you values from which you can reconstruct the user input on command line, and use those arguments if you want. You can completely ignore that, if you don't want to react on passed arguments. *"hould I just avoid using argument registers for my own code"* - no, not as general rule (there may be specific case where it may have some reason to do it like that), MIPS has 32 general purpose registers (some of them have somewhat special features and usage), you can mostly use them any way.